# Upgrading Laravel 6 to 7 I have errors with barryvdh/laravel-cors

Tags: laravel

Upgrading  Laravel 6.14.0 to 7 for my laravel backend app
and reading this doc https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/upgrade#upgrade-7.0
I have errors with support of barryvdh/laravel-cors, as I got erorr in console:

```
Class 'Barryvdh\Cors\ServiceProvider' not found
```

If to comment 1 line In config/app.php :

```
//        Barryvdh\Cors\ServiceProvider::class,
```

and reference in app/Http/Kernel.php

I passed console commands(like config cache).

But I got CORS errors in my vue/cli app.

I tried to search in net for Barryvdh\Cors
and seems here https://packagist.org/packages/barryvdh/laravel-cors there is support for laravel 7,
but if installation was changed?

Also I found this  https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors  package.
Is it replacement of Barryvdh\Cors? Which steps have I to take to run my app as laravel 7?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Laravel 7 includes first-party support for configuring Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS). It looks like you will have to add the fruitcake/laravel-cors dependency. here is the [CORS Support](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/upgrade#cors-support) upgrade information from the Laravel documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Yes the vendor name has changed, you can find the upgrade guide [here](https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors#upgrading-from-0x):

**Upgrading from 0.x**

> When upgrading from 0.x versions, there are some breaking changes:
>
> 1. The vendor name has changed (see installation/usage)
> 2. Group middleware is no longer supported.
> 3. A new 'paths' property is used to enable/disable CORS on certain routes. This is empty by default!
> 4. The casing on the props in cors.php has changed from `camelCase` to `snake_case`, so if you already have a `cors.php` file you will
>      need to update the props in there to match the new casing.

You can find the installation / usage guide [here](https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors#installation).

PS:

Laravel 5.5 and onward support package auto-discovery so you don't have to add anything into `config/app.php` anymore.